# JS blocked in Google Chrome by extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

While browsing a site (facebook to be specific), JS was automatically blocked. And while checking JS content setting, there was entry for facebook to block JS and it was done by extension, as shown in attached image.

I tried to add new entry to allow JS hoping it will override the block entry, but it did not.

Now I cannot enable JS for facebook with other site.

And at this point I am unable to find out which chrome extension is the culprit.

Can we find out the extension? or can we remove that entry set by extension? We are able to delete entry created by us, but not by extension.[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your extensions and then re-enabling them one by one to see which one is causing it?

Comment: Thanks! I did not think this way. As a matter of fact, there was an extension "Quick Javascript Switcher" that was blocking JS. But I know for sure that I did not install it, and don't know how it got installed. But for now it is working. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing.  Let me post that as the answer for you to accept, okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling all your extensions and then re-enabling them one at a time until you find the culprit.  Then you can remove or disable it.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be the only option. There is no API to retrieve which extension enabled what, neither in `contentSettings` nor `management`

Comment: Would the behavior links cover that? (this uses a private api) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc